# Position custom react-leaflet control into leaflet control container

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

In [this example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control/) the the custom control is placed below the actual `leaflet-control-container` element.

```
<div class="leaflet-control-container">
    <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div> <----- Where I want it
    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div>
    <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div> <----- Where it is actually placed
```

This causes that anything in `leaflet-control-container leaflet-top.leaflet-right` div is covered with the custom element.

Is there a way to place this custom element inside `leaflet-control-container`?

Answer (score 0):

That example looks buggy and unnecessarily complex.  Try wrapping the minimap component in a [LayerControl](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#layerscontrol) and using that to set the position:

```js
<LayersControl position="topright">
    <MinimapControl />
</LayersControl>
```

Comment: That again creates the same structure as described in my question. With the difference that now there is the regular leaflet layer control that is overlapping my custom control.